# Subjunctive "в первый раз слышу, чтобы ..." vs. Indicative "в первый раз слышу, что ..."

Tags: грамматика

In conversation, I just said jokingly:

> Ого! В первый раз **слышу**, **чтобы** ты сказала что-то разумное.

I'm wondering if the subjunctive mood with "чтобы" is commonly used like this with the phrase "в первый раз" if you want to emphasise how surprised you are to  hear/see something unusual? Or should I have said:

> Ого! В первый раз **слышу**, **что** ты сказала что-то разумное.

In the case of the past "услышал", on the other hand, I assume the indicative mood with  "что" is the only option:

> Ого! В первый раз **услышал**, **что** ты сказала что-то разумное.

I think my uncertainty comes from the fact that in its French equivalent "C'est la première fois que je + indicative", the subjunctive mood is impossible.

Comment: the 1st and the 3d are more idiomatic than the 2nd, a synonym of **в первый раз** which i personally prefer over it is **впервые**, it works more smoothly and according to Google occurs in this phrase with **слышу** more than twice as often, 28K times, even better to my taste is the wording **Впервые слышу от тебя что-то разумное**

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I can't explain why I feel this way, but when I say something like "Ты небось **впервые** так далеко выбралась, а?", the use of "в первый раз" sounds odd here for some reason.

Comment: formally there's no difference, but **(в) первый раз** is somewhat less harmonious

Comment: after reading Alex_ander's answer i realized that many of the phrases in Google results (if it matters) actually mean what he described, a surprise about someone else's behavior or a fact related by another person which means **it's unheard of that ....**, but not all, so in the sense you've meant it it still occurs albeit more rarely than i initially assumed

Comment: The first sentence isn't totally clear = that you would have said something sensible.

Comment: чтобы in cases like this = that you would, could, might. что ты бы сказала что-то разумное. Just compare it to English; it's the same idea. чтобы is just a combination of что + бы as you know, so just add a would/could somewhere and see what you think.

Comment: @VCH250 Unfortunately, not as simple as that. In Alex_ander's "Никогда не слышал, чтобы ...", the "you would/could/might say" interpretation fits fine, since hearing it has never happened before. However, in my first phrasing, the **fact** of actually hearing it for the first time described in the main clause **clashes** with the **subjunctive mood** "you would/could/might say" described with "чтобы" in the subordinate clause. Despite this, it turns out this phrasing can sound idiomatic to some native speakers. So it goes deeper than simply comparing it to how things work in English.

Answer (score 2):

**Чтобы** is typically used (with past tense) when speaking of something *not* happened. So, your first example sounds like the speaker *denies* the fact (like, *впервые слышу такое!*) of her saying something reasonable earlier (after hearing about it from somebody else). Such a sense is more directly expressed in this way:

> Никогда *не* слышал, **чтобы** ты сказала что-то разумное.

If the speaker just expresses a surprise with an admitted fact or an approval, they don't use **чтобы**:

> В первый раз слышу/услышал, как/**что** ты сказала что-то разумное.

Comment: Здесь вовсе не о "типичности _чтобы_ для прошедшего". Прошедшее упомянуто для ограничительной привязки утверждения к случаю из вопроса (там "сказала" - в прошедшем) и для исключения из рассмотрения пожеланий вроде "некто говорит, чтобы", не имеющих отношения к примерам из вопроса. Ваши примеры подпали бы под "критикуемое" вами утверждение при такой модификации:_Я никогда не слышала, чтобы здесь **выпадал** снег (чтобы он **пел**)._  Призываю вас к сдержанности в эпитетах.

Comment: Прошу прощения,  значит, неправильно поняла.

Answer (score 1):

1.Что and чтобы aren't used with all verbs. Some verbs require only что, others can be followed only by чтобы. And there are verbs which can be followed by both conjunctions.

2 In this case there's  a semantic difference.
Что introduces facts and opinions. Чтобы introduces a wish. (we don't speak about purpose, clauses of purpose are also introduced with чтобы ).

> А вам говорят, **что** ваш друг уже вышел… [Е. Гришковец. ОдноврЕмЕнно (2004)]
>
> ПА говорит, **чтобы** я к ней с этим не приставала. [Л. Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого (2000)]
>
> Ключик упорно настаивал, **что** Вертинский― выдающийся поэт. [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]
>
> Мама упорно настаивала, **чтобы** мы её "правильно поняли". [А. Алексин. Раздел имущества (1979)]

Your first sentence is incorrect. The rest are correct.